# find files not in a list

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, find, diff

I have a list of files in `file.lst`. 
Now I want to find all files in a directory `dir` which are older than 7 days, except those in the `file.lst` file. How can I either modify the find command or remove all entries in `file.lst` from the result?

Example:

`file.lst`:

```
a
b
c
```

Execute:

```
find -mtime +7 -print > found.lst
```

`found.lst`:

```
a
d
e
```

so what I expect is:

```
d
e
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Pipe your `find` command through `grep -Fxvf`:

```
find -mtime +7 -print | grep -Fxvf file.lst
```

What the flags mean:

```
-F, --fixed-strings
              Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings, separated by newlines, any of which is to be matched.    
-x, --line-regexp
              Select only those matches that exactly match the whole line.
-v, --invert-match
              Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.
-f FILE, --file=FILE
              Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.  The empty file contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.
```

Comment: Will this work? the output from `find` for e.g. file `a` in cwd is `./a` which will cause `-Fx` to fail to match...

Comment: How about if I need to dynamically construct the list of files, e.g. with `ssh xyz.com 'ls /var/backups/daily | tail -10'`? This would be instead of have the list of filenames in file.lst. I've tried piping here, but can't quite figure it out (my piping-fu is weak).

Comment: This only find the files in file.lst for me and not the inverse

Answer (score 3):

Pipe the find-command to `grep` using the `-v` and `-f` switches

```
find -mtime +7 -print | grep -vf file.lst > found.lst
```

grep options:

```
-v : invert the match
-f file: - obtains patterns from FILE, one per line
```

example:

```
$ ls
a  b  c  d  file.lst

$ cat file.lst 
a$
b$
c$


$ find . | grep -vf file.lst 
.
./file.lst
./d
```

Comment: I think this will match most of the cases.However, if there is a file name as 'aa', probably this will fail

Comment: @ajreal, true, might use `a$` in file.lst to narrow that possibility

Comment: @Fredrik: you should use fixed string pattern. `grep -F` or `fgrep`

Comment: Also consider adding the `-x` option, in addition to using `fgrep`.