# Find all files, then grep all files for those names

Tags: command-line, grep, find

I want to run a command on a directory to print out all files in that directory, then `grep` all files recursively for those found file names, basically to check and see if X file is used in any `PHP` or `HTML` files in a directory. If X file is found to NOT be in any files, print it's name.

I have this so far, I can't figure out how to pass to `grep` what I have then print those without results.

```
find . -path ./images -prune -o -name '*' -type f -print | sed 's!.*/!!'
```

I could use `exec` as so:

```
find . -path ./images -prune -o -name '*' -type f -exec grep -R '{}' ./* \;
```

But then I can't `sed` away the `./dir/etc/` from in front of the file names that find gives me.

The other part of the query that is perplexing me is I can't figure out how to get `grep` or find to print those without results in `grep`.

Comment: what search target are your grepping for in your exec example?

Comment: Try using `find ... | xargs grep  -R`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think something like this might help:

```
$ find . -type f -printf "%f\n" | grep --color -R -f - .
```

In this example, `-printf "%f\n"` causes `find` to return only the file name without the path. The result is a file used as the search patterns for grep and is passed as input on `stdin` using `-f -`. The `-R` tells grep to search recursively (which you already know). The `--color` makes things look nice.

To list only the matching file names use `grep -l -R -f - .`. Then to find the files *without* results, you will have to find the files that are not in that list.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7306971/416627) might help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

Use `-exec` to call `basename` and pipe to `grep`:

```
find ./images -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec basename {} \; | grep ...
```

This will print just the filenames of all the files found in `./images`.